# Hexadecimal Offsets

Tags: endianness, hexdump, hex, hex-editors

I was looking at some hexadecimal code and someone told me to look at offset : 0x830880EC
stored as little endian, but what does this mean? Browsing through the offsets listed in HxD Workshop, I see nothing like this, I am pretty sure that 0x is just some form of prefix or something, but I do not know what it means. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think following link can help you derive your answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141262/can-someone-explain-hex-offsets-to-me

Comment: I do not exactly understand what that means especially because the example he uses is with a different size number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HXD you will want to use the GoTo function, then jump to that address, the 0x is just a prefix designating a hexadecimal number, it's only really necessary when actually programming, or to clarify that you are sharing a hex number. Also depending on what you are looking at, the address might be different in HxD. For example, when modding on the xbox 360, a game's memory starts at 0x82000000, but in HxD this address would just be 0x00000000. So based on your starting address, the value could change. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to search for the value 0x830880EC and fetch corresponding offset. 0x is prefix added to hexadecimal number so actual hexadecimal number is 830880EC. You can search for this number and if you do not find it try after changing endianness (byte order).
If we suppose that 83 08 80 EC is big endian then EC 80 08 83 would be little endian or vice-versa. Once you find the value you should be able to calculate corresponding offset.